# Firebase Messaging Unity Plugin shows notifications only in foreground

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

As you guys might know, Firebase released their official (and BETA) Unity plugin for many of their services.
I'm now testing their quickstart sample for FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging), and I'm receiving the Push Notifications on iOS, but only when the app is on foreground, when I close the app or just leave it to run in the background, it won't show any notifications, but as soon as I open the app I will receive all the notifications that were sent while the app wasn't on foreground.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Regards,
Arturo M.

Comment: From your description I think you may be sending data messages which cannot be received while the app is in the background. Try sending notification messages (which go through APNs) and that should allow your app to receive notifications while it is in the background.

Comment: I'm using the Firebase console for this. What should I do? I'm just filling the title and message fields.

Comment: If you are using the console then those messages should go through APNs which should work in the background. If you are only receiving them in the foreground then I'd double check the APNs certificate setup, ensure that the correct bundle IDs are used and the correct one is uploaded to the console.

Answer (score 0):

For background notifications you have to enable the `Remote Notifications` option in `Background Modules` on `Capabilities`...

[image: Capabilities > Background Modules > Remote Notifications]

Or just add this to your Info.plist (which is the same):

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```